# доступ по ftp закрыт по ip адресу, как снять?

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

Где то закрыт доступ по  ftp к серверу по ip адресу. Никак не могу найти. Со своего ip вхожу, удаленному пользователю не могу представить доступ через браузер, идет ошибка unkhown error
Стоит vsftpd: version 3.0.2
linux 3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Aug 14 21:49:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
/etc/hosts.allow /etc/hosts.deny - пустые
Ошибка выходит You do not have permission to viev @System@snap-283922

Comment: У хостера спрашивайте)

Comment: Для удаленной работы с серверами лучше использовать sftp. Уровень безопасности выше

Comment: Только вот проблемы доступа к ftp это совершенно никак не касается